# Using TemplateHaskell to list all names in a namespace

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I want a TemplateHaskell function `variablesInScope :: Q [Name]` that returns a list of the `Name`'s of all the variables in scope.  TemplateHaskell obviously has this information available in order to implement functions like `reify :: Name -> Q Info` and `lookupValueName :: String -> Q (Maybe Name)`.

Does the function I want exist somewhere and I just overlooked it?  Or can it be easily built somehow?

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't do this with just TH, but you can use `haskell-src-meta` to parse a Haskell module as a TH AST.

Comment: Would that require using the IO features of the `Q` monad to load the module, and then send that to `haskell-src-meta`?  yikes.  Also, this can't disambiguate which name to use in the particular scope the splice is at.

Comment: Yes, you need to use IO to actually read the file. I'm not sure I understand your second statement - why would you need to disambiguate if you are getting *all* names? You could open a ticket for a feature request, I suspect that the underlying mechanism which powers TH has all in-scope names available anyways.

Comment: I've created the tickect ([#9699](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9699#ticket)).  What I mean by the second point is that a function might declare a variable called `print`, and then the `print` from `System.IO` would no longer be in scope.  So the result of `variablesInScope` has a pretty complicated dependence on where in the code the splice occurs.

Answer (score 2):

**Unfortunately, you cannot do this with `TH` alone. Try the `haskell-src-meta` to parse the Haskell module as a `TH AST`.**

It will require the IO features of the `Q` monad to load the module though.

*Please reference https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9699#ticket to see the current rough spec*

> (1) Extend ​ModuleInfo (obtained from ​reifyModule) to ModuleInfo [Module] [Name], where [Module] is still the import list and [Name] contains the module's list of exported names.
>
> (2) Add thisModule :: Q Module producing the current ​Module.
>
> (3) Add topLevelNames :: Q [Name] producing a list of top-level names (both exported and non-exported) bound in the current module that would be visible to reify.
>
> (4) Add nestedNames :: Q [Name] (in need of a better name) producing a list of the non-top-level (nested) names visible to reify in this context.
>
> (5) Add parentNames :: Q [Name] (also in need of a better name) producing a list of the names immediately associated with the current splicing context, if available. For example, foo, bar :: $(typeSplice) would see [foo, bar], foo = $(exprSplice) would see [foo], and $(topLevelDecSplice) would see [].
>
> (6) Optional Add isTopLevel :: Name -> Q Bool to detect whether a name is bound at the top level (of the current module?). Something like this could alternately be accomplished by searching through topLevelNames.